# Is it possible to pass a File to AsyncTask in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Is it possible to pass a File to AsyncTask? Like this?

```
public class UploadImagesTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, File> {
    @Override
    protected File doInBackground(String... params) {
```

and would I access that file by doing this?

```
params[2]
```

Comment: almost but you you want your params type to be file instead of string and the result to be something useful. Passing URL's is a better method and documented inn other questions on [SO]

Comment: You can add constructor to your UploadImagesTask that takes File as argument, then use as private field inside doInBackground

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not like that, no.

If you want to pass in a `String` and a `File`, you'll need to do something like this, and trust yourself not to screw up the arguments.

```
public class DoThing extends AsyncTask<Object, String, File> {
    @Override
    protected File doInBackground(Object... params) {
        String stringy = (String) params[0];
        File file = (File) params[1];
        // do hard work
        return file;
    }
}
```

Since all your arguments extend `Object`, when you call the thing, it'll look like this:

```
String aString = stringGettingMethod();
File aFile = fileGettingMethod();
new DoThing().execute(aString, aFile);
```

Alternately, you can pass whatever you want in through constructor arguments.

Comment: Thank you, perfect. I totally get it now!